# including files with $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] on localhost

Tags: php, function, include, localhost, document-root

I just moved my site to my local computer(a mac) but the site is not able to load properly because the include files doesn't seem to be able to include properly.

say eg:

I have the following lines:

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/pages/includes/functions.php');
```

on my index.php but the files are not able to be included properly.

I tried to use the functions in the file but it doesn't seem to be able to run the functions properly as per online.

I tried echo-ing `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` but it shows: `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs`

I'm not sure if that is the full path or if there is anything else i need to add to the url to get my files to be properly included. Perhaps i'm missing something. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: Warning: include(/Applications/MAMP/pages/includes/login.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/pages/includes/functions.php on line 4

Comment: But i already have the proper files in the appropriate directories. I wonder if there is anything with the url directions.

Comment: Oh, what was the problem?

Comment: It was running fine. There was an error on my included script.

Comment: Ah ok. Well am glad it was resolved. You can delete the question then. *Cheers*